# Problems to place the input field at correct position in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I double click the card the dialog pops up, and it is then possible to create comments. So far so good. When creating the comments it is possible to edit it.

The issue is when I edit the text the input filed where I edit the text is placed in wrong position. And cover the "Edit/Delete" paragraph. I want the input filed to be placed when pressing the edit on the text position.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/140/)

JQuery: "click" handler

```
$('#divComments').on('click', '.edit', function () {
        var element = $(this).parent()
        var text = $(this).parents(".CommentStyle").find("label").text();
        var input = $('<input id="attribute" value="' + text + '" />')
        element.children('label,p').addClass('hidden').end().append(input);        
        input.select();

        input.blur(function () {
            var text = $('#attribute').val();
            element.children('label').text(text);
            element.children('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#attribute').remove();
            element.children('label').change();
        });
    });
```

JQuery: Add comment function

```
function addComment(commentString) {

        var container = $('#divComments');
        var inputs = container.find('label');
        var id = inputs.length + 1;
        var data1 = {            
            commentString: commentString
        };

        var div = $('<div />', { class: 'CommentStyle' });

        $('<label />', {
            id: 'comment' + id,
            text: commentString
        }).on('change', function () {            
            data1.commentString = $(this).text();
        }).appendTo(div);      

        $('<br/>').appendTo(div);

        var $Image = $('<img />',
            {
                "src": "/Pages/Images/alert.png",
                "class": "CommentImage",
                "for": "comment" + id
            }).appendTo(container);

        var d = new Date();
        var $fulaDate = $('<div>' + d.getDate()
            + "-" + monthNames[d.getMonth()]
            + "-" + d.getFullYear()
            + "//" + d.getHours()
            + ":" + d.getMinutes()
            + '</div>').addClass('labelStyle').append(' ~').appendTo(div);

        var $edit = $('<p />', {
            class: 'edit',
            text: 'Edit'
        }).append(' ~').appendTo(div);

        var $delete = $('<p />', {
            class: 'delete',
            text: 'Delete'
        }).appendTo(div);        

        div.appendTo(container).focus();

        container.data('comments').push(data1);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply modify the following line

```
element.children('label,p').addClass('hidden').end().append(input);
```

to

```
element.children('label,p').addClass('hidden').end().prepend(input);
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/62QY8/141/)

Comment: How to hide the date? I tried by this code: element.find($fulaDate).addClass('hidden').end().append(input); But seems not to work.

Comment: `element.children('label,p,.labelStyle').addClass('hidden').end().prepend(input);` [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/62QY8/142/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending the input-field as the last element, you should insert it where the label was.

```
$('#divComments').on('click', '.edit', function () {
    var element = $(this).parent()
    var label = $(this).parents(".CommentStyle").find("label");
    var text = label.text()
    var input = $('<input id="attribute" value="' + text + '" />')
    element.children('label,p').addClass('hidden')
    label.after(input)
    input.select();

    input.blur(function () {
        var text = $('#attribute').val();
        element.children('label').text(text);
        element.children('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#attribute').remove();
        element.children('label').change();
    });
});
```

To hide the timestamp, just add `.labelStyle` to the list of elements you want to hide:

```
element.children('label,p,.labelStyle').addClass('hidden')
```